# How to include the html code inside the php echo

Tags: php, html

I have a php file which is called through jquery ajax and I am getting the results in HTML type. I want to show a select box along with selected value. But I am facing a problem when I mix html code inside php's echo.

```
echo '<option <?php if($booklist[$i] == $book){?> selected="selected" <?php }?> value="'.$book_id[$i].'">'.$book[$i].'</option>';
```

Comment: Use string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Can you rewrite my code and show how to do it.  I have already included string concatination but It is giving syntax error when I do the same inside the code for selected value

Comment: If you're echo-ing something you're already working in php code so you no longer need to use <?php and ?> to close the php. Simply use concatenation like Rory suggested and you're good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use short code like below,  (statment  ? true:false) is the same as using

```
if( $booklist[$i] == $book ) {
    echo 'selected="selected"';
}else{
    echo '';
}
```

In short code form, it would be like below:

```
echo '<option '.($booklist[$i] == $book ? 'selected="selected"' : '').' value="'.$book_id[$i].'">'.$book[$i].'</option>';
```

Comment: If this has helped, please tick as your answer. 

Short code isn't always the best solution, but I find for short statements like above, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$selected = "";
if($booklist[$i] == $book) $selected = 'selected="selected"' ;

echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$book_id[$i].'">'.$book[$i].'</option>';
```